# How can I make the state diagram from the code in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, state-machines

How do I draw the state diagram of this state machine?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 Flip-Flops. Each of them can have 2 states.

So your entire Verilog code has 2^2 = 4 states:

- QA=0, QB=0
- QA=0, QB=1
- QA=1, QB=0
- QA=1, QB=1

By using the "CLR" input you get into the state QA=0, QB=0 from anywhere.

The output of your code is "QA". So two of these states have an output of 0 and two of them have an output of 1.

For each of the 4 states you'll have to think what happens when a clock pulse comes and the input is 0 and what happens when the input is 1.

From each of the 4 states you will have (up to) two transitions to another state. Depending on the notation you use you either draw an arrow from a state to the same state or you don't draw the corresponding arrow at all if the state does not change.

Note:

As far as I didn't do a mistake the state after the reset (QA=0, QB=0) cannot be left any more.

Comment: I had already realized that. I do not understand is how I can look at the code and see the states transitions.

Comment: Carmen, for that you just have to get better at Verilog/VHDL. If you can code a FSM, you can create one from the code.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález, transitions in FSM occur when some events happen, either external conditions change, or internal timers (if any) expire. You have to look at possible events in your input vector, and follow the logic of the code. In most practical cases it is done best using simulators, with various input scenarios, since usually FSMs are thousand times more complex than your example, and you simply can't "simply look" and mentally compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

Xilinx Verilog compilers and synthesis tools can recognize a properly written FSM and create a diagram in graphics format. You can download a WebPack ICE version for free. Synplify tools also used to extract FSM from Verilog code. I am sure there are [other tools](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115756/generate-state-diagram-from-vhdl-code).

However, the tools expect certain code style and discipline to do so automatically. A well-written FSM usually contains three "always" blocks, see [this classic publication](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000Boston_FSM.pdf). Your code has no resemblance to anything, that's probably why you have a difficulty to identify states and transitions.